# Count Distinct on multiple stances in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with results of several email campaigns that I ran recently.
Structure is more or less the following:

| consumer_id | campaign | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Campaign 01 | delivered |
| 1 | Campaign 01 | opened |
| 1 | Campaign 01 | clicked |
| 2 | Campaign 02 | delivered |
| 2 | Campaign 02 | opened |

etc
I want to have the number of people who opened each campaign at least once. That means that if, for example, consumer_id opened "Campaign 01" and "Campaign 02", it would be counted as 2. But if consumer_id opened "Campaign 01" 5 times and "Campaign 02" 3 times, it still needed to be counted as 2.

In other words and writing "dummy sql", I need to "Sum" the "Count Distinct" of consumer_ids fields where status = "opened" on each and every campaign.

I'm a bit stuck on how to formulate this query. Anyone got any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select campaign_id, count(distinct consumer_id)
from t
where status = 'opened'
group by campaign_id;
```

If you want the campaigns per consumer, then:

```
select consumer_id, count(distinct campaign_id)
from t
where status = 'opened'
group by consumer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a CTE that does a select distinct on consumer id, campaign where status = opened.

Then query the CTE and count the records by campaign

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simply

```
select campaign, count(distinct consumer_id) 
from CampaignTable 
where status='opened' 
group by campaign
```

Check it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca410d/3

Answer (score 0):

1. Because you want count for each consumer and your table has same consumer repeated multiple times this gives an indication that you should group by consumer in your query.
2. For each such group of consumer there could be multiple campaigns and each campaign can occur multiple times so you should count distinct campaigns
3. you only want campaigns with opened status so that should be your filter (where clause)

> ```
> select consumer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT campaign)
> FROM campaign_table
> WHERE status = "opened"
> GROUP BY consumer_id
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score -1):

```
select campaign, count(*) as consumers
from (
select consumer_id, 
campaign, 
count(*) as opened
from table
where status='opened'
group by consumer_id, campaign
) q
group by campaign
```

In Google Big Query:

```
select campaign, count(*) as consumers
from (
select consumer_id, 
campaign, 
count(*) as opened
from `storied-surface-316019.test1.campaign_table` 
where status='opened'
group by consumer_id, campaign
) q
group by campaign
```

Anyway I have to say that answer from Gordon Linoff is a better and simpler solution

Comment: Please explain to OP how you build this query and/or explain it part by part

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for the very late reply. This syntax makes sense, but when I try to apply, this is the error I get on Google Big Query:

  SELECT list expression references column internal_customer_id which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:3]

Comment: I think the problem could be the way BigQuery expects you to name the table. This worked fine: